# Different validation for the same element name in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a XML file like this:

```
<myNode>
   <myProperty name="Title" value="MyTitle" />
   <myProperty name="ProductId" value="123456" />
</myNode>
```

Is it possible to write an XSD to validate that the first property ("Title") must be a string, and the second property ("ProductId") must be an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly you can't do that. XSD for your XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="myNode">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="myProperty">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

To solve your issue you can create XSD for folowing XML:

```
<myNode>
    <Properties>
       <Title value="MyTitle" />
       <ProductId value="123456" />
    </Properties>
</myNode>
```

Comment: Sadly I don't have control over the XML file. I'm just trying to validate as much as possible using the XSD, though in this case it doesn't look it'll be much use.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that with XSD. See if http://www.schematron.com/ can help you with this.